# Netbeans keeps on restarting

Tags: java, windows, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, nokia-s40

I've installed the Nokia sdk 1.1 and chose to integrate the sdk with Netbeans IDE. Afterwards I tried closing the Ide but the Ide keeps on restarting and reinstalling the plugins. What can fix be the problem? I tried restarting the computer but still no change. The Ide wont stop restarting. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the same problem. It happens because NetBeans does not have enough privilege to update. Kill NetBeans by Task Manager -> Right click on the shortcut -> Run as Administrator. Now when you close NetBeans, it won't restart anymore.

Comment: Yes, but it do it later! is there any real fix, not semi-solution

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem where *Netbeans* automatically restarts after closing it.
I found that it tries to update **JUnit** plugin in the starting of the program but cannot complete successfully.
Then, I run *Netbeans* as Administrator and the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this problem is caused by failed updates. In my case, the solution was to go to Netbeans’ installation path and empty the subfolder enterprise\update\download completely. After that it started normally again, and a new attempt to install the update was then successful

This site worked for me:

http://blog.ginchen.de/en/2013/09/26/netbeans-startet-nach-dem-schliessen-sofort-neu/

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS users: You can fix this by creating an AppleScript with the following code:

```
do shell script "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\\ 8.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans" with administrator privileges
```

(adjust the path to your NetBeans installation as needed), and exporting it as an application. When you launch it, the system will ask for administrator privileges before starting NetBeans, the updater works as expected, and NetBeans stops restarting all the time...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the shortcut
go to properties
click on advanced
check the box that says "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Just start Task Manager and kill the Netbeans process. Now your Netbeans IDE will stop restarting. Now run Netbeans IDE as an administrator. Now it won't restart. Enjoy! That solution works for me. I hope it works for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways:

1- You can end task the "update" from the task manager. It solves your problem for this time but you will have the same problem when you open the Netbeans again.

2- Run Netbeans as Administrator. It will give the updater to finalize the updates and it will fix the issue forever.